# show client with minimum number in a sql query

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables:
 
`client` : (backoffice_users_id, idfile, validation_file)
`transmission` : (backoffice_users_id, idfile, nbr_files)

I want to show the client who has the **minimum** number of files and with validation_file=1

I did something like this, it gives me the minimum number but with validation_file=0 not validation_file=1, can anyone help me please?

```
SELECT `transmission`.* 
FROM `transmission`
INNER JOIN `client`
ON client.backoffice_users_id=transmission.backoffice_users_id 
WHERE (transmission.idfile='2') 
  AND (client.validation_file<>0) 
  AND (transmission.nbr_files=(
         SELECT min(nbr_files) 
         FROM transmission 
         WHERE transmission.idfile='2')) 
GROUP BY `client`.`backoffice_users_id`
LIMIT 1
```

Comment: check! there is a spelling mistake in the code "validation_fiche" should be "validation_file" hope that is not the error

Comment: Hi Betty, welcome here. You have a `nbr_files` field in `transmission`. What do you count as minimum number of files? Lowest value of `nbr_files` or lowest value of the sum of `nbr_files` for the same `backoffice_users_id` or ...?

Comment: no no , it's not a spelling mistake , it's working for me , it gives me the minimum row but of the client how has validation_file=0 not the one who has validation_file<>0 , because in my example i have two clients , one with nbr=3 and validation_file=0 and other with nbr=4 and validation_file=1

Comment: hi peter , i count the lowest value of nbr_files for each client , but this client must have validation_fiche=1 , in my sql query it doesn't work  , it shows me the lowest value but the clause validation_fiche=1 doesn't work and its not a spelling mistake

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what your `transmission.idfile='2'` means so only answering the 'minimum number of files and with validation_file=1'-part and with the minimume number of files within one single transmission (not summed over multiple transmissions):

```
SELECT * FROM `transmission`
INNER JOIN `client` ON 
    `client`.`backoffice_users_id` = `transmission`.`backoffice_users_id` AND
    `client`.`validation_file` = 1
ORDER BY `transmission`.`nbr_files` ASC
LIMIT 1
```

Comment: i will explain better , i have two table :  affectations :(idaffectations , backoffice_users_id,idsous_risques,validation_fiche) the second table conseillers_sous_risques: (backoffice_users_id,idsous_risques,nbr_sous_risques) , for example i have two client , the first one have bakckoffice_users_id=2 , idsous_risques=2 , validation_fiche=0,nbr_sous_risques=2 , the second client have backoffice_users_id=3 , idsous_risques=2 , validation_fiche=0,nbr_sous_risques=4 , my query show me the first client not the second even if he have validation_fiche=0

Comment: i didn't solve it , it seem's that i still have the same problem , the validation_file=1 don't work , he always shows me the line who had minimum number but with validation_file=0